# Snapshot working for Documents[index] but not for Document(ID)

Tags: flutter, snapshot, stream-builder

I want to access stream builder based on Document ID rather than Document Index.
Please help.

```
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){

              if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data.....');
              return
                  Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]["Name"]),);
```

Comment: you will have to use filter to find document by an id

Comment: I want to have snapshots of all the documents in collection ('users').
I want to know if it is possible this to access by index; can we not access it by document ID in the same manner.